# form.as_table in django

Tags: django, django-forms

```
form = EmailForm()
return render_to_response('books/send_mail.html', {'email_form': form})
```

When i am using form.as_table in my template, all the fields are getting rendered in the same line : `(Email:         Subject:          Message:      )`.

How can i render these form fields in seperate lines using as_table. I dont want to use as_p or as_ul, because they do not have proper alignment.

Comment: Can you show us the form code? I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    attach = forms.Field(widget = forms.FileInput)
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)

Comment: did you wrap your form in table tags? ("you'll need to provide your own <table> tags"). What does the rendered html of your form/template look like?

Comment: Thanks arie, I had missed the table tags...now it is displaying fine

Comment: Nice. I turned my comment into an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Shame he never did accept it eh?   But thanks - it helped me too.   I'm surprised that I don't see table row tags in the rendered page when I don't put the table tags in the template!

Answer (score 12):

Did you [wrap your form in table tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#displaying-a-form-using-a-template)?

> You can also use form.as_table to output table rows (you'll need to provide your own  tags)